# Flag Curvature in Finsler Geometry

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Does anyone know what is the *flag curvature* in Finsler geometry? I looked for this definition, but I don't find any answer.

Comment: You might look, for example, at Chern-Chen-Lam *Lectures on Differential Geometry*.

Comment: If you have access to "An Introduction to Riemann-Finsler Geometry" by Bao, Chern and Shen, it is defined on pages 68-69 there.

Comment: Have a look in here, at the 11th page (the page numbered 207), section number 1.2: http://library.msri.org/books/Book50/files/06BR.pdf Pay attention to figure 1.2 in particular for some visual intuition.